# Variable for joining a header value AND/OR a delimeter to ordered values in Google Sheets (1B)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, flatten, google-query-language, textjoin

In this shared [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vig4TOZC8oRTlWlaw3Zd6SeTuLo1pGqpl5m1zXQISKA/edit?usp=sharing) there are values in a range, contactenated in a specified order, how can I maintain the specified order while specifying 2 variables:
A) when to combine the  "header value" and "cell value" into a header/value pair and
B) when to add a delimiter

A header/value pair are displayed with the following equation:

```
    =ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(
 IF((A2:D4<>"")*(REGEXMATCH(A1:D1, "^\d+_")), "♥"&A1:D1&" "&A2:D4, )), 
 FLATTEN(A1:D1), 1), "\d+_", ),,9^9))), "♥", CHAR(10)))
```

[image]

All header values with a preceding number are displayed in order in the above image.

**Goals**
However, as in the following image, there are times when it would be useful to

1. Not to include the header value

2. add one or more variable delimeters (ie `CHAR(10), " , "` after the cell value string and other times when it would help to

[image]

**Possible approach:**

1. In the above image, a number + an underscore ex `1_Name` (B1 )can represent a parameter to include the header/value pair and a number + tilda `4~Math` (A1) can represent a parameter to exclude the header value
2. Zero or more delimeter variables (>1 represented by `&`)can be provided after a pipe to designate the delimiters to include afer the resulting string (value or header/variable pair)

Since the above equation, already adds a `CHAR(10)` delimiter I believe it would make sense to specify values after a pipe to represent a delimeter variable. As in the image below, this parameter would be inserted into the formula in that space.

[image]

For example, in B1 the value after the pipe `CHAR(10) & CHAR(10)` would add two line spaces. In A1, the value after the pipe `", "` would simply add a comma without a new line space.

The shared sheet is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Vig4TOZC8oRTlWlaw3Zd6SeTuLo1pGqpl5m1zXQISKA/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stuff in your row 1 after pipe `|` can be accessed only as plain text and not as formula input. therefore it's better to have `,` commas without double-quotes and instead of `CHAR(10) & CHAR(10)` use a unique symbol twice like `♦♦`:

see the image for recommended changes highlighted by yellow:

[image]

```
=INDEX(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(FLATTEN(QUERY(REGEXREPLACE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(
 TRIM(IF((A2:D4<>"")*((REGEXMATCH(A1:D1, "^\d+_"))+(REGEXMATCH(A1:D1, "^\d+~"))), 
 IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:D1, "\d+_(.*:)"))&" "&A2:D4&REGEXEXTRACT(A1:D1, "\|(.*)"), ))), 
 FLATTEN(A1:D1), 1), "\d+_", ),,9^9))), "♦ ", "♦"), ",$", ), "♦", CHAR(10)))
```